# JavaScript await async method with then() executing then() immediately

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following scenario that is not behaving as I expect:

```js
async function sleep(milliseconds) {
    await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(() => { resolve(); }, milliseconds)});
}

async function logMessage(message) {
    await sleep(100);
    console.log(message);
}

async function taskA() {
    await sleep(2000);
 
    await logMessage('In taskA');
}

async function taskB() {
    await taskA().then(logMessage('In taskB'));
}

taskB();
```

When I call taskB, I expect taskA to complete before entering the then.  I expect this output:

```
In taskA
In taskB
```

However, what actually happens is that logMessage('In taskB') is called immediately, not after taskA completes, so the output is this:

```
In taskB
In taskA
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Change to `await taskA().then(()=>logMessage('In taskB'));` and execution order will be as expected. You are immediately invoking `logMessage('In taskB')`

Comment: Your code as written is passing the *return value* from calling `logMessage()` to that `.then()` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be  `await taskA().then(()=>logMessage("In taskB"));` not `await taskA().then(logMessage('In taskB'));`

```js
async function sleep(milliseconds) {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, milliseconds);
  });
}

async function logMessage(message) {
  await sleep(100);
  console.log(message);
}

async function taskA() {
  await sleep(2000);

  await logMessage("In taskA");
}

async function taskB() {
  await taskA().then(()=>logMessage("In taskB"));
}

taskB();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why using that code fixes the issue, to help later readers. See [answer].